# nested object reactivity vue js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, state-management

I have the following setup for my vue application

```
var store = {
    ...
    state: {
        currentCustomer:{},
    },
};
```

current customer has a property that is an object called payment method

app:

```
 var app= new Vue({
el:'#application',
 data: {
  sharedState: store.state
  }
});
```

and a couple of components:

```
Vue.component('user_search', {
    template: '#user_search-template',
    data() {
        return {
            sharedState: store.state
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getCustomerData: function () {
                            this.sharedState.currentCustomer(c);
        }

    mounted: function () {
        ...         
    }
});
```

and

```
Vue.component('paymentdetails',{
    template: '#payment_details_template',
    data(){
        return{

            sharedState: store.state
        }
    },
    mounted:function(){
            ...

    }});
```

The issue is like this. The payment method component does not bind to the payment details object that is nested inside the current customer object

any suggestions?

Comment: See [Change Detection Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

Comment: make a computed property on the nested proerty. Alternatively force a rerender by changing the key on the component, it will then get the updated data.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I think what you are looking for is a computed property for accessing the data.

```
Vue.component('paymentdetails',{
    template: '#payment_details_template',
    computed{
        sharedState() {
            return store.state
        }
    },
    mounted:function(){
            ...

    }});
```

Maybe give that a try and see how it works.